# How to do sync my events with Google Calendar after Google Sign in

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-signin

I'm performing a demo for syncing my events with Google calendar from a event adding form. I have completed login with Google but now I'm not able to sync with Google Calendar. Its giving me 401 error. help me out please
Here is my code help would be appreciate thanks :)

scheduler

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log(profile);
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
        $('#email').val(profile.getEmail());
    }
$('#addScheduler').click(function (e) {
            var error = '';
            var email=$('#email').val();
            var pkShareProfileId=$('#pkShareProfileId').val();
            var profileName=$('#profileName').val();
            var startDate=$('#startDate').val();
            var endDate=$('#endDate').val();
            var description=$('#description').val();
$.ajax({
                    url: 'schedulerAjax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'pkShareProfileId': pkShareProfileId, 'profileName':profileName, 'startDate':startDate, 'endDate': endDate, 'description': description, 'email': email},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: showResponse
                });
}
 </script>
<form method="POST" id="addSchedulerForm" name="addSchedulerForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <p id="errorMsg"></p>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <input type="hidden" id="pkShareProfileId" name="pkShareProfileId">
                <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox g-signin2"data-onsuccess="onSignIn">
                        Sync With Google Calendar
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="profileName" class="boxShadowEffect label-basic">Profile Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="profileName" placeholder="Profile Name"  name="profileName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="startDate" class="boxShadowEffect label-basic">Start Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate" placeholder="Start Date"  name="startDate">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="endDate" class="boxShadowEffect label-basic">End Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate" placeholder="End Date"  name="endDate">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description" class="boxShadowEffect label-basic">Description</label>
                    <textarea style="resize:none;" placeholder="Description" id="description" name="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-12 col-sm-10 col-lg-12">
                    <input type="button" class="btn hidden-xs btn-primary btn-block btn-flat save" name="addScheduler" value="Save" id="addScheduler" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

SchedulerAjax.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; 
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName("switchit");
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$apiCall = new ApiCall();
if(isset($_POST))
{
  $shareProfileId=$_POST['pkShareProfileId'];
  $profileName=$_POST['profileName'];
  $startDate=$_POST['startDate'];
  $startDate=strtotime($startDate);
  $endDate=$_POST['endDate'];
  $endDate=strtotime($endDate);
  $description=$_POST['description'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  if ($email) {
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
        'summary' => $profileName,
        'description' => $description,
        'start' => array(
            'dateTime' => '2017-03-28T00:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        ),
        'end' => array(
            'dateTime' => '2017-03-29T00:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        )
    ));
    $calendarId = 'primary';
    $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
}
```

Comment: what is the exact error you are seeing.

Comment: 401- Login Required.

Comment: It would help if you could make this a [mcve]. Otherwise, there is a lot of irrelevant code to read through.

Answer (score 0):

You have not properly authenticated the php client library.  So it doesn't have access to do what you are trying to do.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

You might want to try checking the [Calendar PHP quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php).

I have no idea if its even possible to link Google sign-in (Client login) with PHP (server sided) login.  I seriously doubt it.  You may want to consider dropping PHP and just going with JavaScript see : [JavaScript quick start](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js)

Comment: I have no idea with this CLIENT_SECRET_PATH can you please me out with this.

Comment: I'm trying to signin so that I could able to add my events to the loggedin google account calendar.

Comment: If you follow the tutorial I linked https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php Google walks you though how to set everything up.

Comment: I have set up it completely. in dummy its working fine but when I am trying to integrate with lgoogle sign-in its not working...

Comment: sign-in is client side.  php is server side.   php runs before javascript.   How do you think you are going to link them?

Comment: First, I signed in my acc and then in a modal I'm filling event details and then clicking on save button I want to pass authentication information to ajax call that I am using for saving my event in my database

Comment: The problem with the code above that Google_Client() has not been created correctly.   Your code does not contain anything about saving to the database.  Test your php code first once that works figure out how to pass the access token to your javascript.   I still wonder why you are mixing them.